# Golang: create a slice of strutcs

Tags: list, go, struct

I want to create a list of structs that can be returned by a function in a manner as it is in the [go-github](https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/master/github/repos.go#L208) package.

But what is the correct way to create and populate such a list?

I found two ways, e.g., using the `append()`:

```
...
    allowedRepos := strings.Fields("repo1, repo2")

    actualRepos := []Repos{}
    actualRepos = append(actualRepos, Repos{Name: "repo1", URL: "gth.com/repo1"})
    actualRepos = append(actualRepos, Repos{Name: "repo2", URL: "gth.com/repo2"})
...
```

And by a "direct initialization:

```
...
    actualRepos := []Repos{
        Repos{Name: "repo1", URL: "gth.com/repo1"},
        Repos{Name: "repo2", URL: "gth.com/repo2"},
    }
```

They works but both look bit awkward and wrong.

So - what is the best way to do it?

It looks like need to create it using pointer but can't make it work.

Comment: Both approaches are correct they are not wrong. Awkward, or best, is subjective. You can skip the Type in the literal initialization of the slice's elements, ie `[]Repos{{ ... }, { ... }}` is fine. Lastly you can initialize the slice to a specific length and populate it using an index, ie. `make([]Repos, 2)` and then `actualRepos[0] = Repo{ ... }` etc.

Answer (score 1):

> but both look bit awkward and wrong

Actually there is nothing wrong, both approaches are correct and valid.

The only difference - is slice population time.

In 2nd approach you're populating slice during development time, it means this code:

```
actualRepos := []Repos{
    Repos{Name: "repo1", URL: "gth.com/repo1"},
    Repos{Name: "repo2", URL: "gth.com/repo2"},
}
```

always will create slice with 2 elements in it.

But wit 1st approach you can populate slice in runtime using `append()`, like:

```
actualRepos := []Repos{}
for _, repo := range allRepos {
  actualRepos = append(actualRepos, repo)
}
```

so now all depends on `allRepos` and now this code have dynamic behaviour which is determined in runtime.

> It looks like need to create it using pointer

Please pay attention that slice itself passes by reference, for example:

```
s := [...]string{"r", "o", "a", "d"}
s2 := s[:]
s[3] = "x"
```

Result will be:

```
// s = [r o a x], s2 = [r o a x]
```